# How do you conditionally join text in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

So, I thought this would be relatively straightforward for an advanced user, but this one is troubling my brain.

I have a schedule of people:

```
         1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
John D.  a     a        a  l   
Jane D.  a  l  l           a
```

I've indicated for which weeks they will be absent ("a") or late ("l").  Now, for each column, I want to summarize the people who are late or absent. Obviously, I have way more than two people, and this information changes gets updated regularly, so I'd like to do this automatically.

So, for example, I'd like column #1 to output: "Absent: John D., Jane. D".  And for column #2 it would say "Late: Jane D." and column #3 - "Absent: John D.; Late: Jane. D".

Programmatically and logically, it's straightforward, but I can't figure out a spreadsheet formula to make this happen. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Since you consider yourself and advanced user I'm not going into many details and I'll assume that you know how to copy cells and what's the use of `$`.

Lets say that we have your example as is in the spreadsheet starting from cell `A1`. So the first absence of `John D.` is marked in cell `B2`.

Following the steps you'll end up in another sheet in your spreadsheet that will have the row with your desired columns.

- Rename the sheet with the data to `input`
- Add 3 new sheets and name them: `report`, `absent`, `late`
- Under the sheet `absent` in cell `B3` paste that and copy it accordingly to the right and bottom:

```
=IF(input!B2 = "a"; CONCATENATE(input!$A2; ", "); "")
```

- Under the sheet `absent` in cell `B2` paste that and copy it accordingly to the right:

```
=CONCATENATE(B3:B100)
```

- Do exactly the same steps for the `late` sheet by replacing the `absence` to `late` and `"a"` to `"l"`
- Finally, under the `report` sheet in cell `B2` paste that and copy it to the right:

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(absent!B2<>""; CONCATENATE("Absent: "; absent!B2); ""); IF(late!B2<>""; CONCATENATE("Late: "; late!B2); ""))
```

The above example scales very well if in the future you would like to add more filters like `sick`, `vacations`, etc. You can check the [final result](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ajy6Xdgye-hadGoxQk9PZ2pzal9JN1o3SV9vMXFlckE) in action where I also have another way of representing the `report`.

Comment: Great answer, but you can use JOIN which is the same as CONCATENATE but it adds the commas for you!